# how to go through the loop and print the cyclic values

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the following Array:

```
   Nod= ['338', '299', '299', '300', '300', '335', '336', '314', '335', '336', '337', '338', '309', '337', '314', '309']
```

Now i have to write a code such that it Loops through Nod[] and assign certain variables to first two numbers, like the folowing:

1. Node1 = 338
2. Node2= 299
3. Search for Node2(i.e 299) in the remaing sets
4. And assign the adjacent value to Node3 i.e Node3= 300
5. Detele all the numbers which are used
6. Loop ends here and from the next loop it should search for Node3 value and assign it as Node1

Continue the loop untill Nod= = 0

and the result of the code should look like

First loop

```
Node1= 338
Node2= 299
Node3= 300
```

In Second loop

```
Node1= 300
Node2=335
Node3=336
```

In Third loop

```
Node1=336
Node2=314
Node3=309
```

4th

```
Node1=309
Node2=337
Node3=338
```

and Loop Ends here

I am very new to coding and python, pls help me with writing the code. I have  tried with different Loops but couldnt be able to figure out the logic and code. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To me, by your algorithm, you are making things complex. Could you please share what are you actually trying to achieve finally?

Comment: I have mentioned that under (the result of code should look like:) i just Need three different values every time it Loops through                      First loop
Node1= 338
Node2= 299
Node3= 300

Comment: why does it end at `338` is it linked to the beginning

Comment: In the entire Array the values are paired together and in the first Iteration only one should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
node= ['338', '299', '299', '300', '300', '335', '336', '314', '335', '336', '337', '338', '309', '337', '314', '309']
while(len(node)!=3):
    fst_element = node[0]
    snd_element = node[1]
    third_element = node[2:][node[2:].index(snd_element)+1]
    print "fst: %s\t2nd: %s\t3rd: %s"%(fst_element,snd_element,third_element)
    node = [x for x in node[2:] if x != fst_element]
    node = [x for x in node if x != snd_element]
    node = [x for x in node if x != third_element]
    node.insert(0,third_element)
print "last result: " + str(node)
```

The above is what you want, I suppose. I think the result of the last iteration is:

```
Node1=309
Node2=337
Node3=337
```

According to your algorithm the number 338 was already removed from the first iteration.

Happy learning  python.

Comment: Hi, there are two 338s in the Loop and only the number in even Position(i.e Zero posotion) should be removed

Comment: Then u should be able to modify the code to make it run as what you want. Stackoverflow is not a coding service